# Como impeço que o keyboard mexa com o meu layout?

Tags: android, xml

Como impeço que o button mude de sitio   quando o editText puxa o keyboard?
Obrigado desde já.
[image: Botao mudando de sitio]

xml do Butão:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/hora_picker"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ESCOLHER HORA"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Hora"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Hora"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sala" />
```

Comment: Esse seu botão deve estar com `align_bottom`, não?

Comment: Vou editar com o xml do botão.

Comment: Não me parece que esse seja o *xml* do botão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare essa linha na sua Activity dentro do AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    ...
</activity>
```

Conforme explicação do site Android Developer:

> **adjustPan**: A janela principal da atividade não é redimensionada para criar espaço
>   para o teclado de software na tela. Em vez disso, desloca-se o
>   conteúdo da janela automaticamente para que o foco atual nunca seja
>   sobreposto pelo teclado e os usuários possam sempre ver o que digitam.
>   Normalmente, esse comportamento é menos desejável que o
>   redimensionamento, pois o usuário pode precisar fechar o teclado de
>   software para acessar e interagir com as partes sobrepostas da janela.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html